# Bash Scripting : How to alias Ctrl-b plus % to <F12>

Tags: linux, bash, alias, putty, tmux

I am using TMUX, and want to make a shortcut for splitting my window into two vertical/horizontal panes.
I know that using the following commands I can split my screen :

CTRL+b " for Horizontal split.

CTRL+b % for Vertical Split.

But, using CTRL+b every time takes too much time, thus I want to alias the whole splitting to one key F11 or F12. So, then if I press F11 I should do a horizontal split and pressing F12 should do a vertical split.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you trying to turn F12 into a Macro?

Comment: I don't want F12 to be CTRL+b " for the whole system. I only want it to be functional inside putty terminal. Won't using hotkeys and changing F12 to represent CTRL+b " change my F12 setting for the whole system ?

Comment: Thats true, for use only inside the putty terminal, i cannot help you. Sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 2):

In your ~/.tmux.conf, add this:

```
bind-key -n F11 split-window -h
bind-key -n F12 split-window -v
```

Comment: Could you please explain the use of '-n' parameter here. Earlier I have used bind-key keyword (without using -n) - but, in that I had to use Cntr+b too.

Comment: Well there you go. By default, key bindings are added to the prefix key table, meaning you have to use your prefix (C-b by default) first. You can specify another table, for example root table, which is without prefix. Therefore, use -T root, or -n which is the same, to specify key bindings that don't need prefix. See [here](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, and a great link.
Have a good day.